# What is the point of assigning the size of a string?

Tags: c

For an instance if I store ABCDE from scanf function, the later printf function gives me ABCDE as output. So what is the point of assigning the size of the string(Here 4).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    int c[4];

    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%s",c);
    printf("Your Name is:%s",c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. It's rather like getting 10 of your friends in your childhood car. You *can* do it sometimes. But you shouldn't.

Comment: `scanf("%4s",c);`

Comment: `int c[4]` and you're putting five bytes into it (ABCD plus the `\0 to terminate the string). Wrong. Technically this is Undefined Behaviour and you'll get mysterious errors if you persist making mistakes like that.

Comment: @balmy - actually, with "ABCDE" the OP is placing 5 bytes into a block of 8 bytes , assuming that an `int` is implemented as 2 bytes for the OPs platform and that the string is one byte per character.

Comment: @ChrisBD "assuming that an int is implemented as 2 bytes" - why such assumption? Maybe the target project is 16 bit DOS program? Usually `int` is 32 bit (4 bytes), i.e. 4 * 4 = 16 bytes buffer.

Comment: @emptyhua You probably meant `"%3s"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with, don't use `int` array to store strings!

`int c[4]` allocates an array of 4 integers. An `int` is typically 4 bytes, so usually this would be 16 bytes (but might be 8 or 32 or something else on some platforms).

Then, you use this allocation first to read characters with `scanf`. If you enter `ABCDE`, it uses up 6 characters (there is an extra 0 byte at the end of the string marking the end, which needs space too), which happens to fit into the memory reserved for array of 4 integers. Now you could be really unlucky and have a platform where `int` has a so called "trap representation", which would cause your program to crash. But, if you are not writing the code for some very exotic device, there won't be. Now it just so happens, that this code is going to work, for the same reason `memcpy` is going to work: `char` type is special in C, and allows copying bytes to and from different types.

Same special treatment happens, when you print the `int[4]` array with `printf` using `%s` format. It works, because `char` is special.

This also demonstrates how very unsafe `scanf` and `printf` are. They happily accept `c` you give them, and assume it is a char array with valid size and data.

**But, don't do this.** If you want to store a string, use `char` array. Correct code for this would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    char c[16]; // fits 15 characters plus terminating 0

    printf("Enter your name:");
    int items = scanf("%15s",c); // note: added maximum characters
    // scanf returns number of items read successfully, *always* check that!
    if (items != 1) {
        return 1; // exit with error, maybe add printing error message
    }
    printf("Your Name is: %s\n",c); // note added newline, just as an example
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KshitijJoshi - hence @hyde using `char c[16]`

Comment: Please... you are accepting up to 16 characters in a 16 byte buffer. With the terminating zero that gives undefined behavior.

Comment: @nielsen Ooops... Got mixed up with `fgets` size parameter, which includes the terminating 0. I guess this goes to show just how evil C standard library string handling is, by modern standards....

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array must be defined while declaring a C String variable because it is used to calculate how many characters are going to be stored inside the string variable and thus how much memory will be reserved for your string. If you exceed that amount the result is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `int c`  , not `char c` . In C, a `char` is only 1 byte long, while a `int` is 4 bytes. That's why you didn't face any issues.

Comment: This explanation is very oversimplified. The call to scanf still invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @klutt Since, array of size 4 of ints can store 16 bytes, you can store that 6 bytes without any problem.

Comment: That does not contradict what I said

Comment: An `int` is not necessarily 4 bytes. It is at least 16 bits wide and not wider than a `long`. Otherwise, it could be anything.

Comment: I've worked on a system where sizeof(int) = sizeof(short) = sizeof(long) = sizeof(long long) = sizeof(char) = 1 (of course). This answer is far too simple. I conject that at the time of writing that most things currently running programs in C have a 16 bit int.

Comment: @KshitijJoshi To clarify my critique: Your explanation is technically correct. Well, at least if you add the word "probably" somewhere. The problem is that you're giving the impression that this is ok to do, which it is not. For instance, what happens if you trigger a trap representation?

Comment: @Bathsheba So that machine had 16 bit char?

Comment: @klutt: It had a 64 bit `char` !!

Comment: @Bathsheba Woha! Cool!

Comment: @klutt: It was when I was at university. I doubt they make such things anymore.

Answer (score 0):

(Simplifying a fair amount)

When you initialize that array of length 4, C goes and finds a free spot in memory that has enough consecutive space to store 4 integers. But if you try to set c[4] to something, C will write that thing in the memory just after your array. Who knows what’s there? That might not be free, so you might be overwriting something important (generally bad). Also, if you do some stuff, and then come back, something else might’ve used that memory slot (properly) and overwritten your data, replacing it with bizarre, unrelated, and useless (to you) data.

Answer (score -1):

In C language the last of the string is '\0'.
If you print with the below function, you can see the last character of the string.

scanf("%s", c); add the last character, '\0'.
So, if you use another function, getc, getch .., you should consider adding the laster character by yourself.

```
#include<stdio.h>                          
#include<string.h>                         
int main(){                                
  char c[4+1]; // You should add +1 for the '\0' character.
  char *p;                                 
  int len;                                 
  printf("Enter your name:");              
  scanf("%s", c);                          
  len = strlen(c);                         
  printf("Your Name is:%s (%d)\n", c, len);
  p = c;                                   
  do {                                     
   printf("%x\n", *(p++));                 
  } while((len--)+1);                      
  return 0;                                
}
```

```
Enter your name:1234
Your Name is:1234 (4)
31
32
33
34
0        --> last character added by scanf("%s);
ffffffae --> garbage
```

Comment: `(len--)+1` would look much better as `len-- > 0`

Comment: `len = sizeof(c)` - Don't you mean `len = strlen(c)`?

Comment: Overflow is mean to show how 'string' type is working.
So I want to show the overflow count by '+1' in "(len--)+1".
@klutt thank you for your comment, I will fix them.